# Changing language dynamically using i18n in backbone - requirejs project

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js, i18next

I am trying to create an app using backbone and requirejs .
I am trying to include internationalization in the project using i18n(requirejs amd supported plugin).

I want to give the user the option to change the language.

So, how to configure the i18n so that anybody can change the language according to his/her need.

P.S. Template Engine used is Handlebars.

Any other internationalization plugin recommended is also fine.

Here is my project structure.

- js

  - app

    - config

      - appConfig.js
    - init

      - App.js
      - AppInit.js
    - nls

      - home.js (root file)
      - fr-fr

        - home.js
    - router

      - AppRouter.js
    - templates

      - homeTmpl.html
    - view

      - homeView.js
- lib

Here is my index.html page with option to change the language

```
<html>
<head>
<title>i18n test with backbone and requirejs</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/app/config/appConfig" type="text/javascript"
src="lib/require.js"></script>
<style>
#content{
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    top:200px;
    left:100px;
    border: 3px dotted #0F0;
}
#lang{
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Hello World , Good Morning</h3>

<div id ="lang">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="lang" id="en">English</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="lang" id="fr">French</a>
</div>

<a href='#home'>Home</a><br/>
<a href='#about'>About Us</a><br/>
<a href='#contact'>Contact</a><br/>

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the documentation here: http://i18next.com/pages/doc_init.html

```
i18n.setLng('en-US', function(t) { /* loading done */ });
```

If you'd like to use inline JavaScript like in your example, you could do something like:

```
<a href="javascript:i18n.setLng('en');" id="en">English</a>
<a href="javascript:i18n.setLng('fr');" id="fr">French</a>
```

Comment: Hi Lochlan, I am using a backbone-requirejs project where I am going to fetch the language preference from server. How can I implement it?

I am also gunting the js file using grunt-requirejs plugin, but i18n fails to load the language after grunting.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code? Are you successfully retrieving the language setting and re-initialising the plugin on your uncompressed code? Is it only after running compressing via requirejs that you're having troubles?

Comment: Hi Lochlan, I am having difficulty in setting up the project configuration. can u mail me @ er.inboxmail@gmail.com as it is difficult to explain here..

Regards